# How to store the JSX template of React Native in an offline database and fetch it back?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, jsx, offline

How to store the JSX template of React Native in the database? If stored in string format, how to convert it back to JSX after fetching from the database?

For example:
if we store JSX as string format `'<Text>test</Text>'` in realm database. How can we convert it to `<Text>test</Text>` after fetching from the database??

I am using the realm database as an offline database for the React Native app!!